# CSS - don't wrap span contents in fixed width table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with fixed width table cell and span elements (with additional elements inside, text + button). I don't want those span contents to be wrapped (span elements are placed in that cell), like this:

```
<td style="width: 250px;">
  <span>Test<button>Remove</button></span>
  <span>Test<button>Remove</button></span>
  ...
</td>
```

How to achieve this? I tried with white-space but with no success (span contents don't wrap but table cell is not fixed width anymore...) (http://jsfiddle.net/dvjq4/).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I don't want span contents to be wrapped, but spans itself can be wrapped if necessary. But problem is solved.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set your span to display block:

http://jsfiddle.net/hQCwW/1/

```
.ex-element { 
display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the table in some wrapper div and then set `overflow:auto` and `white-space: nowrap;` on the div.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dvjq4/3/)**

### CSS

```
.wpr {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
    display:block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution (inspired by Matthew Trow).

Span element class (in example `.ex-element`) must look:

```
.ex-element {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing white-space: nowrap; from the span element.

```
.ex-element {
   /* white-space: nowrap; */  
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/dvjq4/4/)

Comment: What is your problem? You don't want the spans to be wrapped and you have a fixed width for the table column. You cannot have a single line with all the spans you add. It has to break at some point. Since the width of the table column depends on the width of content when it does not have a white space, you cannot have a fixed width, the width tends to increase.

Comment: Not the spans but content of spans ;) I wrote this code so I tried without white-space before :p I needed label + button together, but other spans (label + button pairs) can be (even must) be wrapped. Just together. Easy, no offence :)